# Copying 1-to-1 relationships with identity fields in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity, foreign-key-relationship, one-to-one

Suppose you have two tables that are in a one-to-one relationship; i.e. the primary key of the child table is also the foreign key that links it to the parent table. Suppose also that the primary key of the parent is an identity field (a monotonically increasing integer that is assigned by the database when the record is inserted).

Suppose that you need to copy records from these two tables into a second pair of identical tables -- the primary key of the parent is an identity, and the foreign key linking the child to the parent is also the child's primary key.

How should I copy records from one set of tables to the other set?

I currently have three solutions, but I'd like to know if there are others that are better.

- **Option 1:** Temporarily disable the
  identity property in the destination
  parent table. Copy records from the
  parent table, then the child table,
  keeping the same values for the
  primary key.  Cross your fingers that
  there are no conflicts (value of
  primary key of source table already
  exists in destination table).
- **Option 2:** Temporarily add a column to
  the destination parent table to hold
  the "old" (source) primary key. Copy
  records from the parent table,
  allowing the database to assign a new
  primary key but saving the old
  primary key in the temporary column.
  Copy records from the child table,
  joining the source child table to the
  destination parent table via the the
  old primary key, using the join to
  insert the record into the
  destination child table with the new
  primary key.  Drop the temporary
  column from the destination parent
  table.
- **Option 3:** Copy sequentially
  record-by-record, first from parent
  to parent, then child to child, using
  DB-provided "identity of last
  inserted record" functions to ensure
  that the link is maintained.

Of these options, I think option 2 is my preference.  Does anyone prefer one of the other two options, and if so, why? Does anyone have a different solution that is "better"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one reason why it is so critical to remember that even if you use a surrogate key (like an identity column), you always need a business key. I.e., there always need to be some other unique constraint on the table. If you had that, then another choice would be to insert the values into the copy of the parent table without the identity values and use that unique key to insert the proper parent value for the child rows.

If you do not have that unique key, then given your situation, I agree that your best solution would likely be Option #2.

Comment: Unfortunately, while most of the tables have natural composite business keys, there are three tables that don't. :(

Answer (score 0):

Before you decide on an approach to copy data to new set of tables, you should investigate following items:

1. a list of tables that reference the data from the parent and child tables (both sets of tables)
2. Are there any stored procedures/triggers that utilize the data in these tables?
3. How does this table get populated? Is there an application/data feed that inserts data in this table?
4. How does the data in this table get deleted?
5. What is the purpose of the primary key beyond ensuring uniqueness in the table? For this you will have to understand how the data in the table is used by the application.

Based on the answers, you should be able to pick the right solution that will meet the requirements of the application.

Answer (score 0):

My money is on Option 1 (see `SET IDENTITY INSERT`, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx).

But: Why are you copying them?

- If you are just altering the table schema, or migrating to new tables and retiring the old ones, why not use `ALTER TABLE`.
- If you are going to run them side-by-side you probably need the keys to match.

But to answer your question, use Option 1, definitely.